# How to add a new (blank) page to a wordpress site with a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on building my first wordpress plugin and seem to be stuck on something.

I'm needing the plugin, when activated, to create a new page using the same styles as the rest of the site; as well as adding a customizable path (/this is the path) to the link.

I have researched how to do this and and have gotten a blank .php file to appear... using this code:

```
//Template fallback
add_action("template_redirect", 'my_theme_redirect');

function my_theme_redirect() {
    global $wpdb;
    $plugindir = dirname( __FILE__ );

    //A Simple Page
    if ( $wp->query_vars[ "pagename" ] == 'event-photo-uploadr' ) {
        $templatefilename = 'custom-uplaodr-page.php';
        if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templatefilename )) {
            $return_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templatefilename;
        } else {
            $return_template = $plugindir . '/themefiles/' . $templatefilename;
        }
        do_theme_redirect($return_template);
    }
}

function do_theme_redirect($url) {
    global $post, $wp_query;
    if (have_posts()) {
        include($url);
        die();
    } else {
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
    }
}
```

What I'm needing to know now is, how could I replace this .php file with one that is in my plugin folder? I'm also wondering how to make a custom link for this page as it needs to be a hidden page only for those with the link.

Must all be run through the plugin as well as get removed when the plugin is deactivated.

I would also like to hear any tips on best practices and improvements on my code. Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic because it's "asking for code", please [read the question's checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Anyway, it's not clear what you want... I suspect it's something [like this](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/page-template-example/). Research in the [**`<plugin-development>`**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes&pageSize=50) tag at [wordpress.se], lots of good material over there.

Answer (score 0):

use the add_action

add_action('template_redirect', 'function name');

then create a function to load and use a require this will over wright your current theme.
you would then need to add the filter in your function.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'loadTheme');

function laodTheme() {
if (is_page('page')){
global $post, $wp_query;
    if (have_posts()) {
        require($url);
        die();
    } else {
        $wp_query->is_404 = true;
    }
}  
}
```

so that should redirect your theme when going to the page 'page' you can change your condition to your need.
i think this is what you were asking.

as for custom links these can be set within your custom theme files.